# Angular2 Module cannot match component child routes

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-routing

So I have an angular2 based web app. The site has a submodule called tutorial with its own sub-router (to navigate through the "chapters"). So here is my app.

**tutorial.module.ts:**

```
import { tutorialRouting } from './tutorial.routes';
import { tutorialComponent } from './tutorial.component';
import { chapterComponent } from './chapter/chapter.component';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    tutorialRouting
  ],
  declarations: [
    tutorialComponent,
    chapterComponent
  ],
  providers: []
})
export class tutorialModule {}
```

**tutorial.routes.ts:**

```
import { tutorialComponent }    from './tutorial.component';
import { chapterComponent }  from './chapter/chapter.component';

const tutorialRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'tutorial',
    component: tutorialComponent,
    children: [
      { path: '/chapter/:id',  component: chapterComponent },
      { path: '', component: chapterComponent }
    ]
  }
];

export const tutorialRouting = RouterModule.forChild(tutorialRoutes);
```

**tutorial.component.ts:**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'tutorial',
  template: `
  <div class="content row">
    <div class="chapters col s3">
        <h3>Chapters:</h3>
        <a *ngFor="let chapter of chapters; let i=index" (click)="clickedItem = i" [class.clicked]="i == clickedItem" class="chapter" [routerLink]="['/chapter', chapter.number]">{{chapter.number}}. {{chapter.title}} </a>
    </div>
    <div class="col s9">
        <h1>Tutorial</h1>
        <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </div>
  </div>`,
  styleUrls: ['app/tutorial/tutorial.css'],
  directives: [codeStepComponent, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES]
})
export class tutorialComponent {
    public chapters = _chapters; //this is an imported 
    clickedItem: number = 0;
 }
```

So when I go to `/tutorial`, then that's fine, I get a list of all my chapters and their links, however, when I click a link e.g. `href="/tutorial/chapter/1"` from the tutorial I get the error:

> Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes: 'chapter/1'

I also tried setting the links as `tutorial/chapter` but I still got the same result. What have I done wrong?

#### Update:

If you want to see the full project, [here](https://github.com/georgeedwards/docs/tree/master/ng2/views) is a link to the relevant part of my full project repo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you set wrong path. Change this line:

```
  { path: '/chapter/:id',  component: chapterComponent },
```

Into this:

```
  { path: 'chapter/:id',  component: chapterComponent },
```

Also, in root routes table (app.routes.ts) you have to add followed line:

```
  { path: 'tutorial', loadChildren: 'tutorial/tutorial.module', pathMatch: 'prefix'}
```

To show angular, where it should try to find your child module. Check this example: http://angularjs.blogspot.com/2016/08/angular-2-rc5-ngmodules-lazy-loading.html

Comment: I am afraid even with that modification, I still get the console error `Error: Cannot match any routes: 'chapter/1'`

Comment: Hm.. If tutorialModule is a child module, you also have to change "export class tutorialModule" into "export default class tutorialModule". Don't have any other idea now :(

Comment: Well I think the module is working, as the `' '` root route nav's to tutorial, but I'll try that anyway.

Comment: Nope, that actually breaks the import (systemJS unexpectedly imported undefined)

Comment: Thanks for the ideas though!

Comment: @GeorgeEdwards, did you add - pathMatch: 'prefix' - into route 'tutorial' in root route config?

Comment: Yep, still same result. I'm using typescript if that makes a difference?

Comment: Nope. It is possible for you to show more code, i.e. root route config?

Comment: Sure, [here](https://github.com/georgeedwards/docs/tree/master/ng2/views) is the whole project's repo.

Comment: Hm.. App.routes is your root route? So where is - { path: 'tutorial', loadChildren: 'tutorial/tutorial.module', pathMatch: 'prefix'} in your root route table?

Comment: it's not, where should that be?

Comment: In root routes table. Look at this entry from angular blog - http://angularjs.blogspot.com/2016/08/angular-2-rc5-ngmodules-lazy-loading.html

Comment: Ahh awesome! That's done it! If you want to edit your answer to include that note, I'll mark it as correct

Comment: For those using webpack:   anyone else that got stumped like me, anytime you use `loadChildren:` you have to implement a new `<router-outlet></router-outlet>`.  I thought because this was some hack to load an ngModule using webpack that I didn't have to implement another `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` but you do, in the main module's html template that you are lazy loading.  If that lazy loaded module has children in their routes you'll need a 3rd router outlet.